# How to select all inputs elements using angularJs

Tags: angularjs, input, uppercase

i need to convert all the string entered to uppercase using angularJs, i tried with jQuery and it works perfectly but i do not know how to manipulate the elements with angularJs.

pd.the project is made in a sigle page so i have lots of controllers and i want to use this function over all the controllers.
 the code below was written in the " ng-run() " function, it works in all the project, no matter the controller is in use (it works while the page is reloaded) .

```
    $("input").keyup(function() {
      this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want capital letters just for the UI and not for anything internal in your JS logic, you can use [an uppercase Filter](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_uppercase.asp) on your text.

Depending on how you're doing your inputs, you could also do something such as tack a function onto `ng-change` for the input. See docs for `ng-change` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange). This also changes the input value to capital letters.

```
<input ng-model="txt" ng-change="txt = txt.toUpperCase()"/>
<h1>{{txt}}</h1>
```

If you're doing something more advanced than simply capitalizing the text, you can instead use a function in `ng-change` instead of an inline command. (I'd recommend this way anyways, since it is easier to debug than inline JavaScript.)

```
<input ng-model="txt" ng-change="makeCapital()"/>
```

Where `makeCapital()` looks like this:

```
$scope.makeCapital = function(){
    txt = txt.toUpperCase()
}
```

If you want to make a *copy* of the text that is capital, but do not want to edit the original text that is being two-way bound, then you can use a function that copies the bound variable into a second variable, and then change the capitalization on that variable.

```
<input ng-model="txt" ng-change="makeCapitalCopy()" />
```

Where `makeCapitalCopy()` looks like this:

```
$scope.makeCapitalCopy = function() {
      $scope.capitalCopy = $scope.txt.toUpperCase();
      // This capitalCopy variable doesn't need to be on the $scope. 
      // If you're not going to display the value back on the view and just want to manipulate it internally, just declare it locally.
}
```

However, for the latter option, depending on what your goal is with the data, if you want to reflect the input back onto the view, I think this is overkill and defeats the point of two-way binding.

[Here is a Plunker showing all three of these.](https://plnkr.co/edit/sFvXVkFlFdHxROeY7wsE?p=preview)